# Is there a way to use base zero numbering in vi?

Tags: vi

Is there a way to use base zero numbering in vi or vim, for line numbers and column/character numbers?

Comment: Top link on Google:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176326/vim-zero-indexed-line-numbers-in-set-number

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I searched with `vi` not `vim` and so missed it.  I guess the answer is "no" then.

Comment: "set relativenumber" is something that I found useful than using the absolute numbering scheme.