# Can I have vi number lines starting from 0

Tags: editor, vi

I frequently use the vi command

```
:set number
```

I recently was trying to align some data that had a zero based index with the line numbers in vim, which has a 1 based index.  Is there a way to have vi start numbering lines from 0, or more broadly from any other starting point?

Comment: It doesn't look like this is possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176326/vim-zero-indexed-line-numbers-in-set-number

Comment: The Q&A you posted indeed indicates that this is not possible.  Another Q&A that I missed is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213373/is-there-a-way-to-use-base-zero-numbering-in-vi    However perhaps (hopefully) something has changed in 4+ years.   One of the comments introduced me to the set relativenumber command.  This ironically partially solves my problem when I keep the cursor over the first line of the file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David's comment led me on a bit of a goose chase eventually finding this link: [Add line numbers to source code in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252766/add-line-numbers-in-vim)

For my purposes what I needed was not necessarily a persistent numbering, but just a temporary one.  Quickly insert/remove line numbers and then resort to the standard numbering.  For this case, I hadn't thought of simply inserting then deleting my own line numbering.  The below works well.  And the possibilities are endless for numbering (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/252774/2816571)

```
%!awk '{print NR,$0}'
```

For a native vi solution to adding numbers then (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/253041/2816571) the below will insert line numbers then the space character:

```
:%s/^/\=line('.').' '/
```

Then (thanks Lance) https://stackoverflow.com/a/4674574/2816571 when done with the numbering, do something like this, but you might need to tweak the search pattern depending if you put a space, comma separator

```
:%s/^[0-9]* //
```

If there is something I am missing inside vim that can do the persistent 0 based numbering, please let me know.